# Using 3rd party library in a .NET Core 3.1 project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget

I have a .NET Core 3.1 project using a 3rd party library. When I use a specific function from that library I get the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution. They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context.

There's no such package in Nuget called "System.Windows.Forms" and it seems like the 3rd party library has a dependency on it. Any idea on how to fix this?
Any help is very much appretiated!

Comment: You should make project a Net project and then target Core 3.1.  The Net library will have the System.Windows.Forms library.

Comment: what 3rd party library? is it reasonably compatible with .net core?

Comment: @jdweng It's a huge project with a big codebase, and it's not really my decision to make. I can bring this to the project manager but I highly suspect he won't like the idea. Either way, thank you for the input!

Comment: @DanielA.White It's SyncFusion's Pdf docs handling class. I suspect it's pretty compatible since there's a lot of code already using their objects, and everything else works fine. Thank you for your input!